# Twilio Sends transactional and promotional SMS

Tags: twilio-api, twilio-php

By using twilio Service provider and twilio sdk , I want to send transactional sms and  promotional sms from single account.
How can i achieve this ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific Question?
Otherwise I would refer to the [Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries), there are a lot Step by Step guides to set up your Twilio sdk.